# Short cut Key for .axml code format in Xamarin Studio(Mac)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I find on SO. and Google but i couldn't find the solution. Whenever i write the code in `.axml` file the format is not well means the code putting space to it's format. I write code this format code is generated.

**Styles.Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>

    </resources>
```

but i want format code like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">

        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
</resources>
```

Any Help be Appreciated..

Comment: `Ctrl-i` is the default code formatter short-cut : Edit` / `Format` / `Format Document`

Answer (score -1):

Are we talking about xaml or xml files? Try to press `Control + K`, keep pressing `Control` and press `D` (without `K`)

Comment: not work. It actual cut that line when press `Control + K`. and `Control + D` not work.